# can not save application settings in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, application-settings

I am creating a application that store basic database connection info like host,user, password and default database name in application settings using User Scope.

I am using .net 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008

I put 4 text boxes in a user control and bound their text property to the application settings individual properties.

```
// 
        // textBox_database
        // 
        this.textBox_database.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(103, 101);
        this.textBox_database.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.textBox_database.Name = "textBox_database";
        this.textBox_database.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 27);
        this.textBox_database.TabIndex = 5;
        this.textBox_database.Text = global::PHP_Code_Generator_2.Properties.Settings.Default.mysql_database;
        // 
        // textBox_password
        // 
        this.textBox_password.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(103, 69);
        this.textBox_password.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.textBox_password.Name = "textBox_password";
        this.textBox_password.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 27);
        this.textBox_password.TabIndex = 4;
        this.textBox_password.Text = global::PHP_Code_Generator_2.Properties.Settings.Default.mysql_password;
        this.textBox_password.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        // 
        // textBox_user
        // 
        this.textBox_user.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(103, 37);
        this.textBox_user.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.textBox_user.Name = "textBox_user";
        this.textBox_user.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 27);
        this.textBox_user.TabIndex = 7;
        this.textBox_user.Text = global::PHP_Code_Generator_2.Properties.Settings.Default.mysql_user;
        // 
        // textBox_server
        // 
        this.textBox_server.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(103, 5);
        this.textBox_server.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.textBox_server.Name = "textBox_server";
        this.textBox_server.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 27);
        this.textBox_server.TabIndex = 6;
        this.textBox_server.Text = global::PHP_Code_Generator_2.Properties.Settings.Default.mysql_server;
```

these text boxes will get user data from users to set their own database info. i have a button that saves the modified info back to the settings file

```
private void button_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

but the design is not being saved. any help anyone?

regards,
Anjan

**To Cyril: Yes i had the code to assign modified value in properties, but then even the scope was set to "User" it said readonly. So i removed the property assignment codes.
now i brought the code back and restarted VS, it works perfect now :D silly me, i should have try this old procedure before.
Thank you Cyril.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... I remember having the same problem a few months ago in one of my projects. Unfortunately I don't recall how I solved it.

Some checks...

1. Try setting the property scope to User in the Project Properties.
2. In the code you've listed I don't see where you set the property (only see you retrieving the property). Where have you set it?