# dynamic Userconifg question

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm working on a program that will sort files based on extension

I currently use a internal dictionary to store the extension/location

```
.jpg  / c:\blab blab\my documents\my pictures
.mp3 / c:\blab blab\my documents\my music
.gno / c:\familytree
```

etc

I would like to make this program less specific to me and allow users to configure what folders get monitored and what type of file extensions go where

the problem I get into is I'm not sure how to write / display the portion of the user config that would store the extension associations

Ideally I would like to display them in a datagridview or something of the sort but I'm completely lost on how i would do that

Thanks if you can help(or even if you cant)

Comment: are you asking how to store your data in the configuration file?

Comment: yes and now. How would i store a dictionary. I can store and retrieve things like a string 

I'm also confused as to what is the best way to display a dictionary so the user can edit it and then save the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into this [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716564/can-not-save-application-settings-in-net-3-5) or this [post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/204082008064658AM/2.aspx). You can also use settings to store the required paths.

Else there is difficult path of saving them in registry. Have a look at this [article](http://codehill.com/2009/03/a-registry-viewer-in-c/) for starting.

Comment: I may have been unclear in my orginal post. I know how to save and retrive simple tings like string from the settings file. I am confused as to what would the best way to store something more complex liek a dictonary and how would the user view it to make changes?

Comment: you can simply serialize the dictionary object to disk! If the user is not going to make changes very frequently it will be a good approach.